# Creating a Search using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, search

I am trying to create a search using JavaScript. I have created the framework, but not sure how to make it that when the user clicks on a dropdown item, it populates the input field with the selected option. What should I do? Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<input class="form-control searchResult" type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search">

<div id="match-list"></div>
```

JS:

```
const search = document.getElementById('search');
const matchList = document.getElementById('match-list');

const searchStates = async searchText => {
    const res = await fetch('countries.json');
    const states = await res.json();

    let matches = states.filter(state => {
        const regex = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`, 'gi');
        return state.name.match(regex);
    })

    if (searchText.length === 0) {
        matches = [];
        matchList.innerHTML = '';
    }

    if (matches.length > 0) {
        const html = matches.map((match, i) => `<div class="dropdown" id="dropdown${i}"><option class="dropdown-text" id="dropdown-text${i}">${match.name}</option></div>`).join('');

        console.log(html);
        matchList.innerHTML = HTML;
    }

}

search.addEventListener('input', () => searchStates(search.value));
```

JSON:

```json
[
  {
  "name":"Afghanistan",
  "phoneCode":"+93",
  "capital":"Kabul",
  "abbr":"AFG"
  },
  {
  "name":"Albania",
  "phoneCode":"+355",
  "capital":"Tirana",
  "abbr":"ALB"
  },
  {
  "name":"Algeria",
  "phoneCode":"+213",
  "capital":"Algiers",
  "abbr":"DZA"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you make a codepen for this?

Comment: on click, do stuff.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better off using the [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) tag. This will directly filter the results and react to click events:

html:

```
<input id="country-input list="countries">
<datalist id="countries"></datalist>
<button onClick="send">Send</button>
```

js:

```
// Store countries array in COUNTRIES
const inputDataList = document.getElementById("countries");

COUNTRIES.forEach((country) => {
  const countryOption = document.createElement("option");
  countryOption.value = country.name;
  inputDataList.appendChild(countryOption);
});
```

To read the input value, just get the `.value` from the **input** element:

```
const countryInput = document.getElementById("country-input");

const sendCountry = () => {
    // Do stuff with countryInput.value
    console.log(countryInput.value);
};
```

Comment: That definitely works and I have implemented that. So now, in order to get what the user selected, I have to grab the value of the <datalist> tag, correct? Or would I grab the value of the <input> tag?

Comment: You would grab the value of the input tag. I've edited my answer ;)